# How to display vertical text (90 degree rotated) in all browsers?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, text-rotation

How can I display vertical text (90 degree rotated) in all browsers?

[image]
<sub>(source: [sun.com](http://blogs.sun.com/oootnt/resource/sbres_1164126054_0__.png))</sub>

Comment: That was a pretty silly thing to say; it's a programming language and, like most, has access to image modification functionality...

Answer (score 7):

The problem is independent from the server side language. If it's not a problem when the vertically rendered text isn't text anymore but an image, choose the [solution provided by tharkun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771378/php-how-to-display-vertical-text-90-degree-rotated-in-all-browsers/771400#771400). Otherwise, there are ways to do it in the presentation layer.

First, there's (at the moment) an IE-only solution, which is [part of the CSS3 standard](http://www.css3.com/css-writing-mode/). You can [check it live](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/verticaltest.html).

```
p {
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
```

The [CSS3 text module](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/css3-text/Overview.en.php) also specify some [properties for text orientation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-text-20030514/#glyph-orientation-vertical).

Other guys do it [with SVG](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/721811-solution-display-text-rotated-90-vertically-firefox-css).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can rotate text with PHP/HTML/CSS. But you can create an image with [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) containing vertical text.

Example:

```
header ("Content-type: image/png"); 

// imagecreate (x width, y width)
$img_handle = @imagecreatetruecolor (15, 220) or die ("Cannot Create image"); 

// ImageColorAllocate (image, red, green, blue)
$back_color = ImageColorAllocate ($img_handle, 0, 0, 0); 
$txt_color = ImageColorAllocate ($img_handle, 255, 255, 255); 
ImageStringUp ($img_handle, 2, 1, 215, $_GET['text'], $txt_color); 
ImagePng ($img_handle); 
ImageDestroy($img_handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function verticletext($string)
    {
       $tlen = strlen($string);
       for($i=0;$i<$tlen;$i++)
       {
            $vtext .= substr($string,$i,1)."<br />";   
       }
       return $vtext;
    }
```

there you go no echo

Answer (score 1):

Text rotation is also possible with other browsers.

CSS:

```
/*Safari*/
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/*Firefox*/
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/*Opera*/
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/*IE*/
writing-mode: tb-rl;
filter: flipV flipH;
```

Comment: While this works across all modern browsers, it's unsupported by older ones.

Answer (score 1):

I use the function below if table header rows are too long. It's quite useful because it's easy to use, fast and you don't have to calculate text height & width. Those css-gimmicks just don't work.

```
#######################################################
# convert text to image and embed it to html
# uses /tmp as a cache to make it faster
# usage: print imagetext("Hello my friend");
# Created by Ville Jungman, GPL-licenced, donated by www.varuste.net

function imagetext($text,$size = 10,$color = array(253,128,46)){
  $dir = "/tmp/tekstit";
  $filename = "$dir/" . base64_encode($text);
  if(!file_exists($filename)){
     $font = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf";
     $box = imagettfbbox($size,90,$font,$text);
     $w = -$box[4] - 1;
     $h = -$box[3];
     $im = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
     $white = imagecolorallocate($im,$color[1],$color[2],$color[3]);
     $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
     imagecolortransparent($im,$white);
     imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $size, 99, $white);
     imagettftext($im,$size,90,$size,$h,$black,$font,$text);
     @mkdir($dir);
     imagepng($im,$filename);
     imagedestroy($im);
  }
  $data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));
  return "<img src='data:image/png;base64,$data'>";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://www.ozoneasylum.com/11093) suggests that you can write text to an image and then rotate the image.

It appears to be possible with IE but not with other browsers so it might be one of those little win for IE6 =)

Comment: IE can do it with an IE-only proprietary tag.  Most other major browsers (Firefox, Safari, Opera, etc.) can do it with an open web standard: SVG.  (Released 2001, still zero support from Microsoft.)  I'm not seeing any win for IE here.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to get vertical text with CSS, so that means that the rotated text has to be in an image.  It's very straightforward to generate with PHP's' `libgd` interface to output an image file.

Note however that this means using one script to produce the image, and another to produce the surrounding web page.  You can't generally (inline data: URI's notwithstanding) have one script produce more than one page component.

Comment: @Verandaguy it wasn't well supported three and a half years ago, when this answer was written

Answer (score 0):

Use raphaeljs
It works on IE 6 also

http://raphaeljs.com/text-rotation.html

Answer (score -3):

```
   function verticletext($string)
    {
       $tlen = strlen($string);
       for($i=0;$i<$tlen;$i++)
       {
            echo substr($string,$i,1)."<br />";   
       }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.